# Feed localized route-names to i18next-express-middleware

Tags: express, internationalization, i18next

I'd like to use i18next to localize my current project. Since its based on expressjs it only makes sense to also use the i18next-express-middleware.

Very important for this project is to have localized routes for seo-reasons. This is what I'd like to manage with the middleware.

Unfortunately the documentation seems quite thin on this topic:
https://github.com/i18next/i18next-express-middleware

I fugured that the following function is essential to setup the localized routes (from the docs):

```
i18nextMiddleware.addRoute(i18next, '/:welcome', ['welcome', 'willkommen'], route, 'get', function(req, res) {
  //endpoint function
});
```

The valid options for ":welcome" are hardcored in this example. Am I correct assuming that the route-names would be stored in the corresponding language-json? How would I extract the route-names from these json-files? I kinda expect i18next to have some helper-functions to achieve this.

Are there any demo-projects on this where I might have a peek at a working solution?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

```
i18nextMiddleware.addRoute(i18next, '/:lng/key-to-translate', ['en', 'de', 'it'], app, 'get', function(req, res) {
  //endpoint function
});
```

`/:lng` -> a param req.params
`/key-to-translate` -> will be translated - so there need to be a key `key-to-translate` in your resourcefile

`['en', 'de', 'it']` languages to support (build the routes for) -> not the translations